# All categories on one page - image and description not showing

Tags: php, magento, categories, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9.2.1 I would like to show all the categories on a normal page. And I am almost there, but I can't get loading the image and description to work.

This is the page: http://www.cameradraagcomfort.nl/categorie-overzicht/

Here is the PHP I used:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <div class="categorieListing">
    <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <div class="span-1-3">
            <h3><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></h3>
            <div class="Collimg">
                <a title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">

                <?php $imageUrl = $_category->getImageUrl() ?>

                <?php if (!empty($imageUrl)) { ?>
                    <img class="sub-image" src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/collections/maddogsandenglishmen.jpg'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
                <?php } ?>
                </a>

                <div class="toggletext">
                  <p><?php echo $_category->getDescription() ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: does `http://www.cameradraagcomfort.nl/skin/frontend/base/default/images/media/collections/maddogsandenglishmen.jpg` exist and do you have permissions to view it?

Comment: No that doesn't exist, but I have replaced that with a url to an image that exists. But that is not the problem, because that is the escape if the category image isn't found. The problem is that the category image can't be found at all. I have searched, but the getImageUrl() should retrieve the image and it doens't.

Comment: Oke, I did some more searching and testing and I think that I'm in the wrong scope somehow. 

$_category->getName() gets the correct name and $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) gets the correct URL. So I don't understand why the imageURL and the Description isn't in the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally some results... The code below is the solution. 
The rest of the code is the same.

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description', 'overzicht'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('overzicht', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position'); ?>
```